# Add node to XML using TRANSACT-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery-sql

I've been struggling with this simple piece of code without result. I'm just trying to add a new node to an XML variable.

```
DECLARE @XML XML;
SET @XML = '<root>
<policyData>
    <txtComentario />
    <idRegProducto>76</idRegProducto>
    <txtDuracion>24</txtDuracion>
</policyData>
</root>';
DECLARE @NODE XML;
SET @NODE = '<newNode>10</newNode>';
SET @XML.modify
('insert sql:variable("@NODE") as first
into (/root/policyData)[0]')
SELECT @XML;
```

There is no errors, but the new node is not showing in the output. Is there something that I must setup first before using XML in SQL Server? Any suggestion why this is not working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to change `[0]` to `[1]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `[0]` you are actually saying `[position()=0]`. The first node has position `1` so you should change the predicate to `[1]` if you want to insert the new node into the first occurrence of `policyData`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wonder why Microsoft doesn't throw an error here to let the user knows that the syntax is not ok..